# Configure root@localhost mail on postfix dovecot postfixadmin virtual mail server using postgresql freebsd 12

Tags: postgresql, freebsd, postfix-mta, dovecot

Using freebsdI I setup a postfix, dovecot, postgresql and postfixadmin virtual email server.  Everything is working to my satisfaction except email to root@localhost and my user email to localhost.  Having done a lot of investigation and some trial I'm not finding the answer.

I looked at mydestination I have localhost listed, I think that is correct.
I tried adding localhost as a postfixadmin domain, this fails the x.x edit.  localhost. does not work either.  Don't really want to change code for obvious reasons.  Localhost will resolve to the correct local ip 127.0.0.1.

Tried using mail to send root@localhost and get a dead.letter file with the message in it.

I am not a email server expert only the first time I've done this so much learning to do.

how do I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you edited the `/etc/mail/aliases` ? maybe you need something like `root: root@your.tld` (then run newaliases)

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/